# What is the correct way for a controller to set up navigation information independently of hierarchy?

Tags: c#, ios, model-view-controller

If I have a view controller that is hosted directly in a `UINavigationController` then I can do this (C#, but Obj-C equivalent is obvious):

```
this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(...);
```

However, if is instead hosted inside a `UISplitViewController` which is inside the `UINavigationController`, then I have to do this:

```
this.ParentViewController.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(...);
```

This seems fragile and too coupled with the view hierarchy. What is the correct way to set up `NavigationItem` from a view without taking a coupling on the view hierarchy?